# dynamically select a checkbox for siblings treenode in Smart GWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have a selectable Tree with checkbox appearance. I need to select all sibling TreeNode on selection of a specific TreeNode.

I could get all the sibling tree nodes, but I don't know what is the attribute name of TreeNode to make that checkbox selected.

Can anybody help me giving some way to select those nodes.

---

```java
compareGrid.addSelectionChangedHandler(new SelectionChangedHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onSelectionChanged(SelectionEvent event) {
        TreeNode node =  (TreeNode) event.getSelectedRecord();
        TreeNode parent = tree.getParent(node);//tree is Tree object

        treeGrid.selectRecord(parent);
        TreeNode[] nodes = tree.getAllNodes(parent);
        for(int i=0; i< nodes.length; i++){
            if(!nodes[i].getAttributeAsBoolean("isSelected"))
                treeGrid.selectRecord(nodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Its good to share what you have done until now for quick help

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following:

```
treeGrid.selectAllRecords();
treeGrid.selectRecord(record);
treeGrid.selectRecords(records);
```

The first method will select all the `TreeNodes` of the tree.

The 2nd one will select only one specified `TreeNodes` of the tree.

And the 3rd one will select multiple specified `TreeNodes` of the tree.

There are multiple overloaded methods for the last 2 methods, which allows you to specify Nodes in terms of, `TreeNode(s)` itself, or index of the `TreeNode(s)`.

Comment: It didnt help, do i need to refresh the tree or anything else after this treeGrid.selectRecord(record) ?

Comment: what are you passing as record?

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't [approve suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2686796) using backticks for emphasis, but reject or improve them - see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88) why

Comment: @TobiasKienzler, Thanks for the correction. I'll make sure to follow this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution quite close (without checkboxes) to what you need.

```java
employeeTreeGrid.addNodeClickHandler(new NodeClickHandler() {
    public void onNodeClick(NodeClickEvent event) {

        if (event.getNode() != null) {
            TreeNode node = event.getNode();
            TreeNode parent = employeeTree.getParent(node);

            if (employeeTreeGrid.isSelected(node)) {
                List<TreeNode> nodesToSelect = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();

                // omit parent (root) if on first level
                if (!"1".equals(node.getAttribute("ReportsTo"))) {
                    nodesToSelect.add(parent);
                }

                TreeNode[] siblings = employeeTree.getChildren(parent);
                nodesToSelect.addAll(Arrays.asList(siblings));

                RecordList recordList = employeeTreeGrid.getOriginalRecordList();

                for (TreeNode treeNode : nodesToSelect) {
                    Record record = recordList.find("EmployeeId", treeNode.getAttribute("EmployeeId"));
                    if (record != null) {
                        employeeTreeGrid.selectRecord(record);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Have to use the `RecordList` and first find required records in order to use `ListGrid.selectRecord()` methods.
Using `SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX` and `SelectionChangedHandler` can be tricky as programmatic selections are going to trigger further selection events.

This is based on [Checkbox tree sample](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#tree_checkbox) with below changes.

```java
// employeeTreeGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
// employeeTreeGrid.setShowSelectedStyle(false);
employeeTreeGrid.setShowPartialSelection(false);
// employeeTreeGrid.setCascadeSelection(true);
employeeTreeGrid.setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.SIMPLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of selected checkbox from tree grid  in smart gwt I have following  solution ListGridRecord[] arrRec = event.getSelection(); sample code is below.

```
employeeTreeGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
employeeTreeGrid.setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.SIMPLE);
employeeTreeGrid.addSelectionChangedHandler(new SelectionChangedHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectionChanged(SelectionEvent event) 
            //selectedCounties  Set to add selected checkbox or deslected checkbox names/title
            if (selectedCounties == null || selectedCounties.size() == 0)
                selectedCounties = new TreeSet<String>();
            selectedCounties.clear();

            ListGridRecord[] arrRec = event.getSelection();
            for (ListGridRecord listGridRecord : arrRec) {
                selectedCounties.add(listGridRecord.getAttribute("Name"));
            }
            // You can do iteration over it if needed

            selectedCounties.remove("All Counties");
            Iterator<String> it = selectedCounties.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                if (it.next().contains("Zone")) {
                    it.remove();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```